# How to Add Hue Effect on UIImage by modifying Pixel Value of Image in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, cocoa-touch

want to add hue filter in iPhone app
   I want to write a code to add Hue Image Effect with different parameter value of Hue value by modifying the pixel value of Image. How can I do this.
Overall I want to add Hue Image Filter by manipulating each Pixel value of Image. But waht the actual value for Pixel in adding Hue effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CoreImage for that, specifically a CIFilter.
There are plenty of examples online, but there's one in the apple developer website that matches exactly what you want:

Go to [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH203-TPXREF101) and check the section "Creating a CIFilter Object and Setting Values", there it shows how to create a hue filter for a given image.